# Excel Center screen on hyperlink cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have come up with the following macro to center the screen on the cell by following hyperlinks from one sheet to another. Unfortunately it doesn't quite work yet. any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

```
'Center screen to cell for map hyperlinks
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
'On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim onCell As Range
Dim VisRows As Integer
Dim VisCols As Integer

Set onCell = Application.Evaluate(Target.SubAddress)
onCell.Parent.Parent.Activate
onCell.Parent.Activate
With ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
    VisRows = .Rows.Count
    VisCols = .Columns.Count
End With
With Application
    .Goto Reference:=onCell.Parent.Cells( _
        .WorksheetFunction.Max(1, onCell.Row + _
        (onCell.Rows.Count / 2) - (VisRows / 2)), _
        .WorksheetFunction.Max(1, onCell.Column + _
        (onCell.Columns.Count / 2) - _
        .WorksheetFunction.RoundDown((VisCols / 2), 0))), _
     scroll:=True
End With
onCell.Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note on my target sheet I have hidden rows and columns that I am not using.

Comment: What do you mean by this? `to center the screen on the cell `. I didn't quite follow. If you can illustrate what you want to accomplish, that would be great.

Comment: It also might be helpful to describe what "doesn't quite work yet". Are you getting an error? Or does it not quite meet your expectations? If the latter, please describe your expected results in greater detail.

Comment: I dont get any errors but the macro doesn't center the screen when the hyperlink is clicked... I have fixed this by removing Application.ScreenUpdating = False on the top of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Say our goal to to click on a hyperlink, jump to another cell as a result, and then position the new ActiveCell near the middle of the screen.  Give this a try:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Application.Goto reference:=ActiveCell, scroll:=True
    With ActiveWindow
        i = .VisibleRange.Rows.Count / 2
        j = .VisibleRange.Columns.Count / 2
        .SmallScroll Up:=i, ToLeft:=j
    End With
End Sub
```

This relies on the fact that after the jump, the active window is setup with the target at the **lower-right** corner.  Using `SmallScroll` allows us to move the window about 1/2 screen down and 1/2 to the right.

Comment: Had a look at this same problem today, and while your solution certainly gave me the functions I needed to solve my problem, it'd be helpful if you actually explained what the different parts of your solution does. Personally I am curious why you use `SmallScroll` instead of `ScrollColumn` and `ScrollRow`. Maybe I'll google the difference, but for future visitors you'll save them some bother by explaining your choices in the answer.

Comment: @eirikdaude  I am not sure my extra words make any sense.

Comment: I suppose it does - thanks for expanding on the answer after all this time :)